# Need to present items in a grid

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I need to present 1+ `Views` in a grid as exampled below, in 3 columns, evenly spaced. The items are dynamically added.

[image: grid example]

I've tried `GridView` but it gave me a scrollable view which i dont want.
I tried `GridLayout` from the support lib, but i cant have even spacing for some reason with adding a `Space` between items.
`TableLayout` seems too much fuss, so i havent checked it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

In order to disabling Scroll on gridView you can try this:

```
gridview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

});
```

Comment: yup,check it out if it still making problem post the code/log.cat